# dwarfdump is empty when using debug options

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, g++, dwarf

Im trying to get DWARF info from a C++ file using dwarfdump. The C++ file is very simple -

```
int foo();
```

I compile it by doing `g++ -g -c test.cpp`. I then do `dwarfdump test.o`, but for some reason I get

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: test.o (x86_64)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
.debug_info contents:
< EMPTY >
```

Why is this? And how can I get my debug dwarf info?

Comment: did you try -gdwarf-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. No debug information was generated. This is because the optimizer realizes that int foo(); is never called and has no declaration, and as such does not need debug info. Changing the function to

```
int foo(){
    int x=5;
}
```

is enough to generate debug info.